# handlers inside a component invoking eachothers code by mistake

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm lost! i have a really simple component but its going nuts.
i got an input with a change function and a button with onclick.
for some reason when i set the state in the onclick i get an error

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component
>   repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or
>   componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

Huh? im not doing any looping whats going on with this error then?
so i comment the line where i set the state and added a console log to see the value. now i discovered a true magic, when i run the code its showing in the console the value from my state without me clicking anything (the only place i use `console.log` is in the click event).

When i do click the button though, nothing really happens.
but listen to this, when i type inside my input, again the console logs the current value in the state!

why the `console.log()` call from the wrong method? is this a bug?

Here is my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myValue: "Hello World"
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    //this.setState({ myValue: value }); // this will error about infinite loop
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ myValue: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input value={this.state.myValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick(this.state.myValue)}>set</button>
        <h3>{this.state.myValue}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing to the `onClick` event a function invocation, and not a function reference.

> im not doing any looping whats going on with this error then?

In the first initial `render` call when you pass the handler function, you actually invoke it. This function is updating the state which triggers another `render` call which you pass again a function invocation that will do another update to the state which will trigger another `render` call and so on.
Hence an infinite loop.

> why the `console.log()` call from the wrong method? is this a bug?

As i mentioned above, you are passing a function invocation, hence on each render you call `console.log(value)` instead of listening to the `onClick` event, and when you change the input (which works as expected) you rerender again and call `console.log(value)` once more. So it's not the `handleChange` that calling the `console.log`,  it is `render` function that is calling `handleClick` which invoke `console.log`.
No bugs or magics here, it may not be the desired behavior but it is the expected behavior according to your code and logic.

You got 2 main options here.

1. **Easy and fast fix:**   Pass a function reference that returns a function with your logic there. I'm using [currying](https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/), so with ES6
   arrow functions is just as easy as adding another parameter and an
   arrow:

   ```
     handleClick = (value) => (e) => {
       console.log(value);
       this.setState({ myValue: value });
     };
   ```

   This approach does have it's advantages, like fast implementation
   and easy to understand and read the code but it may cause
   performance issues.
   You see, you are returning a new instance of a
   function on each render and react will treat it as a new `prop` this
   can interrupt the [diffing algorithm of react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html).

   **A working example:**

```js
    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          myValue: "Hello World"
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

      handleClick = (value) => (e) => {
        console.log(value);
        this.setState({ myValue: value });
      };

      handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ myValue: e.target.value });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div>
              <input value={this.state.myValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick(this.state.myValue)}>set</button>
            <h3>{this.state.myValue}</h3>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
```

2. **A better approach** that is considered as best practice, is to compose a
   component that accepts an event and a parameter as separate `props`
   and will send this value upwards when the event is triggered.
   **For example `MyButton.js`:**

   ```
   class MyButton extends React.Component{
     handleClick = e =>{
       const {onClick, clickValue} = this.props;
       this.props.onClick(clickValue);
     }

     render(){
       const {children} = this.props;
       return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{children}</button>
     }
   }
   ```

   **A working example:**

   ```js
       class MyButton extends React.Component{
         handleClick = e =>{
           const {onClick, clickValue} = this.props;
           this.props.onClick(clickValue);
         }

         render(){
           const {children} = this.props;
           return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{children}</button>
         }
       }

       class App extends React.Component {
         constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.state = {
             myValue: "Hello World"
           };
           this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
           this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
         }

         handleClick = (value) => {
           console.log(value);
           this.setState({ myValue: value });
         };

         handleChange = (e) => {
           this.setState({ myValue: e.target.value });
         }

         render() {
           const {myValue} = this.state;
           return (
             <div>
               <div>
                 <input value={myValue} onChange={this.handleChange} />
               </div>
               <MyButton clickValue={myValue} onClick={this.handleClick}>set</MyButton>
               <h3>{myValue}</h3>
             </div>
           );
         }
       }

       ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
       <div id="root"></div>
   ```

By the way, you don't need to `bind` the handlers to the `class` when you're using arrow functions. [it binds the `this` automatically](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus).

> The body of ES6 arrow functions share the same lexical this as the
>   code that surrounds them, which gets us the desired result because of
>   the way that ES7 property initializers are scoped

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you are passing a function invocation than a function reference, so the simple and **recommended** change that one needs to do is to give a reference to a thick arrow function (or anonymous function):

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myValue: "Hello World"
    };
 }

  handleClick = (value) => {
    console.log(value);
    // No longer gives error
    this.setState({ myValue: value });
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ myValue: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input value={this.state.myValue} onChange={ () => {this.handleChange();} } />
        </div>
        <button onClick={ () => {this.handleClick(this.state.myValue);} }>set</button>
        <h3>{this.state.myValue}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Now when the `<App />` component is rendered it no longer has the function invocation as the value in `onClick` or `onChange` event listeners, instead, it has a reference to the anonymous function which in turn calls your `handleClick()` and `handleChange()` functions. Hope it helps! :)